# ReCaptcha V3 Invisible: Uncaught (in promise) Request timed out

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

The following bit of JavaScript is giving me errors about 50% of the time.

```
grecaptcha.ready(() => {
    grecaptcha.execute('XXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXX_XXXXXXX', {action: 'XXXXXXXX'}).then(token => {
        this.rootNode.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<input type="hidden" name="g-recaptcha-response" value="' + token + '">');
        this.onRecaptchaKeyAdded(token);
    });
});
```

It's being called on pageload, and then submitted later with the form. This error is occurring a little while after the page loads (suggesting what the error says, the request timed out).

[image: Recaptcha Error]

Tried a lot of different solutions. No .catch method is available on the promise returned from google, so there's no way to catch the error and simply retry.

Comment: I was also getting this and found that it was because the element it was attached to was removed from the page.  Maybe check that the element it rendered to is still there?

Comment: @tgf Interesting thought, but I even rewrote the code inside the callback to just create a new input element and inject it below the form element, still with same result

Comment: Did you ever find a solution or what's the cause of this issue?